# Google Places URL from Address

Tags: google-places

I want to link to my google places listing using the address.

This is being done automatically as I have hundreds of addresses.

The format shown in the share on google maps is `https://www.google.com/maps/place/name+of+place/@lat,long,zoom` however the lat/long is not always selecting the correct places listing.

In some cases the location selected is several states away which makes no sense, though the map is always zoomed to the correct coordinates and the correct listing is right there on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a combination that seems to work:

`https://www.google.com/maps/search/name+of+place,+address+of+place/@lat,long,zoom`

Apparently search works if you're very, very specific.